# Get all previous sampler results (redirects) in JMeter's JSR223 Assertion

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am hitting one API using JMeter. 
The URI that I am hitting (Test API-0) will return 302 Found and redirect it to Test API-1 which will again return 302 Found and redirect it to Test API-2.  Test API-2 will return 200 OK if everything is fine.

[image]

I want to get the *protocol*, *host*, *path*, and *response code* of Test API-0 , Test API-1, and Test API-2.

In JSR223 Assertion Groovy language, I tried

```js
def url = prev.getURL();
def protocol = url.getProtocol();
def host = url.getHost();
def path = url.getPath();

log.info('Full URL: ' + url.toString())
log.info('Protocol: ' + protocol )
log.info('host: ' + host )
log.info('path: ' + path )
```

But this will only give me the Test API-2 only (The latest URI only).

I also tried with

```
log.info("Previous Response URL is: " + ctx.getPreviousResult().getURL());

log.info( "The Sample URL is : " + SampleResult.getUrlAsString() );
```

Again same result. I only get the Test API-2 only (The latest URI only).

How can I get all Test API-0 , 1 , and 2 ?

---

**[UPDATE 10 Dec]**:

The working solution given by user7294900 :

In JSR223 Assertion window

```js
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

 SampleResult[] subResults = prev.getSubResults();

   subResults.each { it ->  
   def url = it.getURL();
   def protocol = url.getProtocol();
   def host = url.getHost();
   def path = url.getPath();

   log.info("URL: " + url )
   log.info("Protocol: " + protocol )
   log.info("host: " + host )
   log.info("path: " + path )
   
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get also sub results using [prev.getSubResults()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSubResults--) and get data from the array

```
 SampleResult[] subResults = prev.getSubResults();
```

> array containing the subresults for this sample

You can iterate each sub results:

```
subResults.each { it->
   def url = it.getURL());
   def protocol = url.getProtocol();
   def host = url.getHost();
   def path = url.getPath();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea works awesomely. But there are some errors in the codes that makes the compiler grumpy. I put the working codes at the bottom of my question. Thanks heaps.